# Brew Installation

Tags: curl, homebrew, rvm

I want to install brew on my mac (10.8.5). For that purpose I have installed Xcode and command line tools as well. I have updated curl as well. Now I am getting this error:

curl: (35) error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

I have already tried many available solutions to this error but not able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Naila!

Sorry, OS X 10.8.5 is too old to be supported by Homebrew. It only supports the last 3 or so versions of macOS, so macOS 10.11 El Capitan and newer as of April 2019.

Try using [Tigerbrew](https://github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew) for older Macs.